# Multiple forms with Flask keeps saying I haven't defined forms

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am trying to set up two different forms on the same Flask page with validators, but it keeps telling me my forms are not defined. I get error:

The code is designed to allow users to input a number and check if it is abundant, perfect, or deficient, and then with a separate form to allow users to define a range and get how many abundant, perfect or deficient numbers there are within that range.

My code is as follows:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import IntegerField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired
from perfect_numbers import classify, listInRange

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'DontTellAnyone'

class PerfectForm(Form):
    inputNumber = IntegerField('input a number', default=1, validators=[InputRequired(message='Please input an integer')])

class PerfectRangeForm(Form):
    startNumber = IntegerField('input a number', default=1, validators=[InputRequired(message='Please input an integer')])
    endNumber = IntegerField('input a number', default=1, validators=[InputRequired(message='Please input an integer')])

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form1 = PerfectForm(request.form, prefix="form1")
    num = 1
    Classify = classify(num)
    if form.validate_on_submit() and form.data:
        num = request.form1['inputNumber']
        Classify = classify(form1.inputNumber.data)
        return render_template('index.html', form1=form1, num=num, classify=Classify)
    return render_template('index.html', num=1, form1=form1, classify=Classify)

@app.route('/aliRange', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def aliRange():
    form2 = PerfectRangeForm(request.form2, prefix="form2")
    startNumber = 1
    endNumber = 1
    aliquot = 'abundant'
    Classify = classify(num)
    ListInRange = listInRange(startNumber, endNumber, aliquot)
    if form2.validate_on_submit() and form2.data:
        startNumber = request.form2['startNumber']
        endNumber = request.form2['endNumber']
        aliquot = request.form2['aliquot']
        ListInRange = listInRange(startNumber, endNumber, aliquot)
        return render_template('index.html', form2=form2, startNumber=startNumber, endNumber=endNumber, ListInRange=listInRange)
    return render_template('index.html', form2=form2, startNumber=startNumber, endNumber=endNumber, ListInRange=listInRange)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

index.html:

```
{% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>WTForms</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <form action="/" method="POST">
        <dl>
          {% if form1 %}
          {{ form1.csrf_token }}
          {{ render_field(form1.inputNumber) }}
          {% endif %}
          <input type="submit" value="submit1">
        </dl>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div>
      {{ num }} is {{ classify }}
    </div>

    <div></div>

<div>
  <form action="/aliRange" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
      <p>Input a start number and an end number to return a list of...</p>
      <select class="form-control" action="/aliRange" name="aliquot" method="POST">
        <option value = 'abundant'>Abundant</option>
        <option value = 'perfect'>Perfect</option>
        <option value = 'deficient'>Deficient</option>
      </select>
      <p>...numbers within that range</p>
      <form action="/aliRange" method="POST">
        <dl>
          {% if form2 %}
          {{ form2.csrf_token }}
          {{ render_field(form2.startNumber) }}
          {{ render_field(form2.endNumber) }}
          {% endif %}
          <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="submit">
        </dl>
      </form>
    </div>

  </form>
  The {{ aliquot }} numbers between {{ startNumber }} and {{ endNumber }} are:
  {{ listInRange }}
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Error I get atm is: AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'form1'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't get Flask to work with multiple forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49860929/cant-get-flask-to-work-with-multiple-forms)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

You can simplify your code using a single view, using the `submit` value to differentiate the handling of the first form and the second one.

The modified code is:

```
class PerfectForm(Form):
    inputNumber = IntegerField('input a number', default=1, validators=[InputRequired(message='Please input an integer')])

class PerfectRangeForm(Form):
    startNumber = IntegerField('input a number', default=1, validators=[InputRequired(message='Please input an integer')])
    endNumber = IntegerField('input a number', default=1, validators=[InputRequired(message='Please input an integer')])
    aliquot = StringField('input a kind', default='perfect')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form1 = PerfectForm(request.form, prefix="form1")
    form2 = PerfectRangeForm(request.form, prefix="form2")

    num = 1
    Classify = classify(num)

    startNumber = 1
    endNumber = 1
    aliquot = 'abundant'
    ListInRange = listInRange(startNumber, endNumber, aliquot)

    if request.form.get('submit') == 'submit-1':
        if form1.validate_on_submit() and form1.data:
            num = form1.data['inputNumber']
            Classify = classify(num)
    elif request.form.get('submit') == 'submit-2':
        if form2.validate_on_submit() and form2.data:
            startNumber = form2.data['startNumber']
            endNumber = form2.data['endNumber']
            aliquot = form2.data['aliquot']
            ListInRange = listInRange(startNumber, endNumber, aliquot)
    return render_template('index.html',
        num=num, classify=Classify,
        startNumber=startNumber, endNumber=endNumber, aliquot=aliquot, ListInRange=ListInRange,
        form1=form1, form2=form2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and the modified template `index.html` is:

```
{% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>WTForms</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <form action="/" method="POST">
        <dl>
          {{ form1.csrf_token }}
          {{ render_field(form1.inputNumber) }}
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit-1">
        </dl>
      </form>
    </div>
    {% if num %}
    <div>
      {{ num }} is {{ classify }}
    </div>
    {% endif %}

    <hr />

    <div>
      <form action="/" method="POST">
        {{ form2.csrf_token }}
        <div class="form-group">
          <p>Input a start number and an end number to return a list of...</p>
          <select class="form-control" action="/aliRange" name="aliquot" method="POST">
            <option value = 'abundant'>Abundant</option>
            <option value = 'perfect'>Perfect</option>
            <option value = 'deficient'>Deficient</option>
          </select>
          <p>...numbers within that range</p>
          <dl>
          {{ render_field(form2.startNumber) }}
          {{ render_field(form2.endNumber) }}
          </dl>
          <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit-2">
        </div>
      </form>
      <div>
        The {{ aliquot }} numbers between {{ startNumber }} and {{ endNumber }} are:
        {{ listInRange }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

OLD:

You are using `form1` in the template but passing `form` inside the template context:

```
render_template('index.html', form=form1, num=num, classify=Classify)
```

You can either change `form1` to `form` inside the template, or pass `form1=form1` in the above line.

If you are rendering multiple forms inside the same template, you have to pass all the respective form variables: `form1`, `form2`, ... from all the views rendering that template. Otherwise the template rendering will raise the error you are seeing.

If you are interested in having a single form rendered among all the possible ones inside the template, you can use conditional rendering using

```
{% if form1 %}
<div>
  <form action="/" method="POST">
    <dl>
      {{ form1.csrf_token }}
      ...
    </dl>
  </form>
</div>
{% endif %}

{% if form2 %}
<form action="/aliRange" method="POST">
...
</form>
{% endif %}

...
```

Also, your html seems incorrect to me, because you have a form nested inside another form. Not sure about what you are trying to obtain there.

Comment: I don't know if I've understood correctly, but that doesn't seem to change anything? And why 'form1=form1' and not 'form=form1'?

Comment: Because inside the template you'll have the variables passed to the context. If you do `form=...`, then you'll have the variable `form`, not `form1` (even if it contains what was `form1` inside the view). You can pass `form=form1`, but then inside the template, you have to use `form`, and not `form1`.

Comment: Even when I do 'return render_template('index.html', form1=form1, num=num, classify=Classify)' and change everything in index.html to reflect this eg: '{{ form2.csrf_token }}' I still get jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'form2' is undefined

Comment: I think I understood your question better, you are rendering multiple forms but for different views, which pass each one only a single form. That's not possible, you have to pass all the forms from each view rendering the template, otherwise the missing ones will raise that error. You can use an `{% if %} ... {% endif %}` to prevent rendering of the missing forms, if that is suitable, otherwise you have to pass all the forms from the different views.

Comment: I think that's nearly fixed it - I get 'AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'form1''

Comment: Yes, you have to fix the form processing when the user has submitted the data. In other words, you have to differentiate the form creation for the initial rendering from the from object instantiation for the user submission. You'll need an `if request.method == 'POST':` and inside that create the form object like `form1 = PerfectForm(request.POST, prefix="form1")`, ... See the official Django [docs on view handling of forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#the-view)

Comment: OK I guess Django and Flask must be the same in this respect - but request doesn't have a post attribute?

Comment: sorry, I was thinking of Django! Disregard my previous comment :-) Where are you getting the AttributeError on `form1` exactly?

Comment: It's when I click on submit

Comment: I guess it's `submit1`, right? Btw, with Flask you have to pass `request.form` to the form constructor, like in `form1 = PerfectForm(request.form, prefix="form1")` and in the other view `form2 = PerfectRangeForm(request.form, prefix="form2")`

Comment: Honestly I can't follow - I'm not sure if I've got this right so I'm updating my code in my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169098/discussion-between-marco-pantaleoni-and-davtho1983).